# update field every hour in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, jobs

I have the following query in a job, it is scheduled to run every hour of L-V.

All the records that are made in the table in the FCH_FIN field have an exact time, for example: 7:00:00 to 19:00:00.

Then I create a temporary table and pass the data from my original table, and I want to go through my temporary table to get the difference in time between the system time using GETDATE () and the time of the record in the FCH_FIN field, if this is less then update active to 0.

Query:

```
DECLARE @count INT;
DECLARE @fch2  DATETIME;
DECLARE @seconds INT;

CREATE table #Suple
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ACTIVO NCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    FCH_INICIO DATETIME NOT NULL,
    FCH_FIN DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #Suple 
    SELECT * 
    FROM Original 
    WHERE ACTIVO = 1 
      AND CONVERT(DATE, FCH_FIN) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());

SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM #Suple;

WHILE @count > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @seconds = DATEDIFF(S, GETDATE(),FCH_FIN) 
    FROM
        #Suple 
    WHERE 
        ACTIVO = 1 
        AND CONVERT(DATE, FCH_FIN) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())

    IF (@seconds < 3)
        UPDATE Original  
        SET ACTIVO = 0

    DELETE TOP(1) FROM #Suple
    SET @count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Suple);
END

DROP TABLE #Suple
```

This query does not update anything

Table:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing this in a loop in the first place? But look at your update statement. You are updating every single row in Original every iteration of the loop. But this should not be using a loop at all. Your ENTIRE code block here can be reduced to a single statement. You don't need temp tables or loops for this.

Also using shorthand in date functions is a [challenge](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations).

```
Update Original 
where ACTIVO = 0
    AND CONVERT(DATE, FCH_FIN) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
    and DATEDIFF(Second, GETDATE(),FCH_FIN) < 3
```

Comment: only modify this and work correctly "SET ACTIVO = 0 where ACTIVO = 1"